# What is the correct way to implement a constructor in android, application context in particular?

Tags: android, constructor, android-context

What is the correct way to implement a constructor in android?

It seems that in an Activity or Service 'onCreate()' is where the magic happens.

The reason I ask is because I would like to be sure I'm doing the right thing declaring
attributes in the top of my classes (Context in particular) and then setting the attribute values inside onCreate.

```
// Activity launched via an Intent, with some 'extras'
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context;
    private String foo;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the object attribute for later use, good or Bad to do this?
        context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent fooIntent = getIntent();
        foo = fooIntent.getStringExtra("foo");
    }

    private void someMethodThatNeedsContext() {
        // For example:
        Cursor c = this.context.getContentResolver().query(foo, xxx, xxx);
        // Or is it better practice to:
        // A) Pass the context as a local variable to this method
        // B) Use getApplicationContext() locally when needed
    }
}
```

Maybe either of these options is ok, and I'm over thinking it?
Any specific reading and/or suggestions you may have would greatly be helpful to me.

Comment: Do not use `getApplicationContext()` unless you know *precisely why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`. It is infrequently needed.

Comment: Great suggestion, I can't believe how quick you guys are off the mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B - Since you can call `getApplicationContext()` from any non-static methods in your Activity class.
In fact, Activity is derived from Context too (Somewhere in the inheritance tree..) so you can just do:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver()....
```

You don't have to keep a reference to a context. *Especially* not static, that can cause problems.

And you are correct - since you usually don't create your own constructor for Activities, you put the code for construction in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct that initialization is supposed to take place in `onCreate()`. You don't really need neither to store a reference to a context, nor to call `getApplicationContext()`. Your activity *is* a context itself, so you just use wherever you need a context. For example, making a toast within an activity:

```
Toast.makeToast(this, "Some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a method inside your activity, so you can call `getApplicationContext()` anywhere in your code, you don't need to use a local variable :

```
Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(foo, xxx, xxx);
```

Also remember that the activity itself *is* a context (the `Activity` class is derived from `Context`), so generally you can use `this` whenever you need to provide a context ( for example when creating an Intent : `new Intent(this, ...)`).

Comment: Makes sense, I guess my concern was with any additional overhead by the call to getApplicationContext, but it sounds like it is simply a getter, that won't need any specific resources?